# Sharing data between nodes using Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is how I launch the Spark job :

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class MyDriver\
  --master spark://master:7077 \
  --executor-memory 845M \
  --deploy-mode client \
  ./bin/SparkJob-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The class `MyDriver` accesses the spark context using :

```
val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf())

val dataFile= sc.textFile("/data/example.txt", 1)
```

In order to run this within a cluster I copy the file `"/data/example.txt"` to all nodes within the cluster. Is there a mechanism using Spark to share this data file between nodes without manually copying them ? I don't think I can use a broadcast variable in this case ?

Update :

An option is to have a dedicated file server which shares the file to be processed :  `val dataFile= sc.textFile("http://fileserver/data/example.txt", 1)`

Comment: It's not within Spark itself, but if you run Apache Hadoop then HDFS allows you to ingest a data file once and have the same file URI accessible to all nodes in the cluster.

Comment: @Jeremy Beard Instead of hdfs I could use http and share the file between nodes using : "val dataFile= sc.textFile("http://fileserver/data/example.txt", 1)" ?

Answer (score 1):

`sc.textFile("/some/file.txt")` read a file distributed in hdfs, i.e.:

- `/some/file.txt` is (already) split in multiple parts which are distributed a couple of computers each.
- and each worker/task read one parts of the file. This is useful because you don't need to manage which part yourself.

If you have copied the files on each worker node, you can read it in all task:

```
val myRdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 100) // 100 tasks
val fileReadEveryWhere = myRdd.map( read("/my/file.txt") )
```

and have the code of `read(...)` implemented somewhere.

Otherwise, you can also use a [broadcast variable] that is seed from the driver to all workers:

```
val myObject = read("/my/file.txt")  // obj instantiated on driver node
val bdObj = sc.broadcast(myObject) 

val myRdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 100)
              .map{ i => 
                // use bdObj in task i, ex:
                bdObj.value.process(i)
              }
```

In this case, `myObject` should be serializable and it is better if it is not too big.

Also, the method `read(...)` is run on the driver machine. So you only need the file on the driver. But if you don't know which machine it is (e.g. if you use `spark-submit`) then the file should be on all machines :-\ . In this case, it is maybe better to have access to some DB or external file system.